# Using id from one table to read value from another table using Linq in sub query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, lambda

Hi I have following ling query

```
 var lst=(from p in db.business 
        where p.id == id
        select new pO
        {
            pName = p.name,
            newStructure = p.p_disc.Select(x=>
                                            new newStructure 
                                            {
                                                post_date=x.post_date,  
                                                posted_by_id=x.person.last_name.Where(x.posted_by_id==x.person.p_id)
                                            })
                             });
```

newStructure class is

```
public class newStructureProject
{
        public int posted_by_id { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime post_date { get; set; }
        public person person  { get; set; }

}
```

In the following line of query I am trying to use posted_by_id in the newStructure to read the last and first name from person table.

```
posted_by_id=x.person.last_name.Where(x.posted_by_id==x.person.p_id)
```

I get intelisense error "string does not contain defination for where.....
Please let me know how i can use it in my query to use posted_by_id to read last name and first name in person table, they have foreign key relation.
Thanks

Comment: What are the entities, and what are the relationships between them?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `posted_by_id=x.person.last_name.Where(x.posted_by_id==x.person.p_id)`

Comment: Just added entities to the post

Comment: basically from p_disc has person_id using that person_id i am reading name of the person from person (entity)

Comment: just use person, navigation property instead. x.person.last_name gives you the name of the poster.

Comment: @Rahgooy I have to select the right person_id cant pick any

Comment: your query selects the desired post, isn't it? and the desired post has a person(navigation property),right? the purpose of navigation property is to save you an additional search for foreign key. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

try this for last name.

```
posted_by_id=x.person.Where(x=>x.posted_by_id==x.person.p_id).Select(x=>x.last_name).FirstOrDefault()
```

you need to apply the where clause first on the object and then select the property value you need.

Comment: Intelisense wont let me chose where with x.person